# Delete user profiles with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that deletes user profiles older than 30 days with powershell and excluding some users like admins accounts.
I've though maybe the script has to be signed by the domaincontroller or something, but i'm not sure if that will be the solution.
When i try to run it on a other directory it works but when i use it on c:\Users i get an error
Does anyone know what i have to change?
Error:

> ```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a
>  policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution
> policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information p
> lease see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
> At line:1 char:46
> + ...  -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'H ...
> +                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
> ```

The Code:

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "15"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Users"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Folders = get-childitem -path $TargetFolder | 
Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | 
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 
foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    if($Folder -notlike "user1")
    {
        if($Folder -notlike "Administrator")
        {
            if($Folder -notlike "user2")
            {
                if($Folder -notlike "Public")
                {
                    if($Folder -notlike "NetworkService")
                    {
                        if($Folder -notlike "LocalService")
                        { 
                            if($Folder -notlike "user3")
                            {
                                if($Folder -notlike "user4")
                                {
                                    write-host "Deleting $Folder" -ForegroundColor Green
                                    Remove-Item -recurse -Force C:\Users\$Folder 
                                    #Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue... `n";
                                    #$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                                }                             
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Cannot delete $Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify your `if` considerably: `if ($Folder -notin "user1", "Administrator", "user2")` etc. You're not actually using the `-like` operator and performing equals checks; so `-in` will work. If you _do_ want like comparisons then you can do `if ($Folder -notlike "user*" -and $Folder -notlike "*Service")` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but indeed i could simplify the if structure, but my main concern is actually the ExecutionPolicy error, but i'll simplify my if structure.

Comment: Are you running the script as an administrator?

Comment: I'm logged in as an administrator and when i open powershell ISE as administartor i get the same error

Comment: From `get-help Get-ExecutionPolicy -full`
You can use Unblock-File file cmdlet to unblock a digitally unsigned script without changing the execution policy.
`PS C:\>Unblock-File -Path "Start-ActivityTracker.ps1"
PS C:\>Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
PS C:\>Start-ActivityTracker.ps1
Task 1:`

This command shows the effect of the Unblock-File command. The command does not change the execution policy.
However, it unblocks the script so that it runs in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: It looks like you have a GPO that sets a executionpolicy that blocks you from running the script.

Comment: Do i have to put the unblock-file command at the top of my script?

Comment: Frode F. do you know were i can find this settings in the gpo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my script which I have used sometime ago:

Most code is commented, so that should be clear.  If you have any questions please ask.

```
# ********************************************************************************************************(**
# *                                                                                                        **
# * Short description: Check profiles if they can be deleted - unused profiles will be deleted.            **
# * Full description: * User running this script can specify the time which will check if profile contains **
# *                     any newer files than limit.  If yes such profile is skipped.                       **
# *                   * User can specify which directories will be excepted from this search               **
# *                   * User can specify which file suffixes will be ignored when the date will be checked **
# *                   * User can specify custom path for the profiles                                      **
# *                                                                                                        **
# * Creator   :  Patrik Svestka                                                                            **
# * Created   :  21/08/2017                                                                                **
# * Version   :  1.0.1                                                                                     **
# *                                                                                                        **
# * Changes description: 1.0.0 - First Public version - Init release                                       **
# *                      1.0.1 - Added license type, minor changes to the header                           **
# *                                                                                                        **
# * PowerShell compatibility: 2.0 , 4.0  and probably newer (untested)                                     **
# * PowerShell tested versions: v2.0.50727, v4.0.30319                                                     **
# *                                                                                                        **
# * License: MIT                                                                                           **
# *                                                                                                        **
# * TODO: ability to run the script remotely                                                               **

# to test remote connection - Get-WmiObject -ComputerName <server_name> Win32_Service -Credential $credentials
# Or manually from PowerShellEnter-PSSession <server_name> -Credential domain\<user_id>

# ***********************************************************************************************************


# **********************************************************
# Test run?
# **********************************************************
# when you want to test what will be deleted
$test_run = $true;
If ($test_run) {
    Write-Warning -message 'Test run ENABLED - for actual DELETION set $test_run to $false' -verbose;
    "`n";"`n";
}


# **********************************************************
# User configuration
# **********************************************************

# $credentials = 'domain\<user_id>';
# $server_name = '<server>';

# Profiles that contain file newer than 90 days will be exempted from deletion
$time_definition=@{'1m'="-0"};

# TODO: test for more periods - not tested yet!
# e.g more time frames - $time_definition=@{'1m'="-30"; '3m'="-90"; '6m'="-180"; '12m'="-360"; '18m'="-540"}

# running script path
$current_path = (Resolve-Path .\).Path;
$log_file = "$($current_path)\delete_files.log";

$folder_to_cleanse = 'E:\t\temp_profiles\'; #'C:\prg'

$excluded_directories = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();

# All excluded profiles:
$excluded_directories.Add('All Users')       | Out-null;
$excluded_directories.Add('Administrator')   | Out-null;
$excluded_directories.Add('Default User')    | Out-null;
$excluded_directories.Add('LocalService')    | Out-null;
$excluded_directories.Add('NetworkService')  | Out-null;

# Extensions excluded from date validation - these files will not influence the date check 
# (will be deleted too if all others are found older)
$excluded_file_types = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();
#$excluded_file_types.Add("*.bat", "*.cmd", "*.ps1") | Out-null;

$profile_directories = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();


# **********************************************************
# The script's start
# **********************************************************

$newer_file_exist = $Null;
$files_to_delete = $Null;

# If previous log file exists delete it (only during test run)
If ((Test-Path -Path "$log_file") -and ($test_run)) {
    Write-Verbose "Deleting previous log file $log_file." -verbose;
    Remove-Item $log_file
}

# get all directories except excluded ones
$profile_directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_to_cleanse -exclude $excluded_directories | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | % { $_.Name }

# if $profile_directories found to be deleted => exit
If ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($profile_directories)) {
    Write-Warning -message "No profile directories to delete.  Exiting." -verbose;
    Exit;
}

# search in profile directories that are left after exclusion
# for all periods defined in time_definition
ForEach ($profile in $profile_directories) {
    ForEach ($time in $time_definition.GetEnumerator()) {
        Write-Verbose -message "Now processing the following profile: $folder_to_cleanse$profile." -verbose;
        $test_current_pathPath = Test-Path -Path "$folder_to_cleanse$profile";
        If ($test_current_pathPath) {
            # check if any newer than $time_definition are present within the profile structure
            # LastAccesstime can be empty! It is better, less issues, to use LastWriteTime.  If you must use LastAccessTime use a check for ::IsNullOrEmpty
            # LastWriteTime must be greater than current day - $time.Name (e.g. -90 days)
            $newer_file_exist += Get-ChildItem -Path "$folder_to_cleanse$profile" -recurse -Force -exclude $excluded_file_types | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $FALSE} | where {($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') -gt (get-date).adddays($time_definition.$($time.Name)).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')};
        }

        # if any new file than the limit found the whole profile directory will be skipped (testing if $newer_file_exist $null)
        If ($newer_file_exist) {
            # add the top directory into excluded directory
            $excluded_directories.Add($profile) | Out-null;
            $newer_file_exist=$Null;
            Write-Verbose -message "The profile $profile will be excluded from deletion process." -verbose;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

# excluding the directories with newer files than limit defined by user
$profiles_with_path = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_to_cleanse -exclude $excluded_directories | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}

# perhaps all $directories are now excluded?
If ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($profiles_with_path)) {
    Write-Warning -message "No directories to delete all probably filtered.  Exiting." -verbose;
    Exit;
}

# get all files to be deleted
ForEach ($dir in $profiles_with_path) {
    # to check
    $test_current_pathPath = Test-Path -Path $dir
    If ($test_current_pathPath) {
        #write-host 'Currently writing for these months:'$($time.Name);
        $files_to_delete += Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $FALSE} | % { $_.FullName }
    }
}

# **********************************************************
# Messages for the user
# **********************************************************
Write-Verbose -message "List of profiles to be deleted:" -verbose;
ForEach ($profile_to_delete in $profiles_with_path) {
    Write-Verbose -message "$profile_to_delete`n" -verbose;
}
Write-Verbose -message "The total count of non-excluded profile directories: $($profiles_with_path.Count)" -verbose;

Write-Verbose -message "==========================`n`n" -verbose;

Write-Verbose -message "List of excluded directories:`n" -verbose;
ForEach ($excluded_profile in $excluded_directories) {
    Write-Verbose -message "$folder_to_cleanse$excluded_profile`n" -verbose;
}
Write-Verbose -message "Total count of excluded directories: $($excluded_directories.Count)" -verbose;

Write-Verbose -message "==========================`n`n" -verbose;
Write-Verbose -message "Total directory count (both to be deleted and excluded): $($($profiles_with_path.Count)+ $($excluded_directories.Count))`n" -verbose;

# **********************************************************
# Test run or actual deletion process
# **********************************************************
If ($test_run) {
    ForEach ($file in $files_to_delete) {
        $file | Out-file -Encoding 'Unicode' -FilePath $log_file -Append # >> $log_file
    }
    Write-Verbose 'This number of files would be deleted:' -verbose;
    Write-Verbose "Found $($files_to_delete.Count) files marked for deletion." -verbose;
} Else {
    $files_deleted = 0;
        # delete files
        If ($files_to_delete) {
            ForEach ($file in $files_to_delete) { 
                #Remove-Item $file -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Remove-Item $file -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                If ($? -eq $true) {
                    $files_deleted ++;
                    #Write-Verbose -Verbose "$File deleted successfully!"
                }
            }
        }
        # delete directories
        $directories_deleted = 0;
        ForEach ($dir in $profiles_with_path) { #
            Remove-Item $dir -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            If ($? -eq $true) {
                $directories_deleted ++;
                #Write-Verbose -Verbose "$File deleted successfully!"
            }
        }
Return "Total files to be deleted: $($files_to_delete.count)","Total files Deleted: $files_deleted", "Total Directories deleted: $directories_deleted"
}
```