# Delete any user profiles that haven't been logged into in the last 6 months using Cim and Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I want to free up some C Drive space on my servers by removing user profiles that from C:\users who haven't logged into the server in the last 6 months.  I connect to the servers using PowerShell Cim commands.

So far I have only found the `Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -ClassName Win32_UserProfile` command that will list users profiles but it doesn't list the last logon time for each user.  Is there another command that can be used to list UserProfiles with LastLogon?  Once I have that list I want to delete any profile that hasn't logged into the server in the last 6 months.

Comment: [`Win32_NetworkLoginProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkloginprofile) class includes `LastLogon` property

Answer (score 0):

[How to delete user profiles older than a specified number of days in Windows](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-delete-user-d86ffd3c)

This PowerShell script sample shows how to delete user profiles older than a specified number of days.

```
Example 1:  

C:\Script\RemoveLocalUserProfile.ps1 -ListUnusedDay 1

Example 2: 
C:\Script\RemoveLocalUserProfile.ps1 -DeleteUnusedDay 1 -ExcludedUsers “marry” 

# Begin Script
If ($ProfileInfo -eq $null) 
{ 
    Write-Warning -Message "The item not found." 
} 
Else 
{ 
    Foreach ($RemoveProfile in $ProfileInfo) 
    { 
        #Prompt message 
        $Caption = "Remove Profile" 
        $Message = "Are you sure you want to remove profile '$($RemoveProfile.LocalPath)'?" 
        $Choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]` 
        @("&Yes", "&No") 

        [Int]$DefaultChoice = 1 

        $ChoiceRTN = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Caption, $Message, $Choices, $DefaultChoice) 

        Switch ($ChoiceRTN) 
        { 
            0
            { 
                Try {$RemoveProfile.Delete(); Write-Host "Delete profile '$($RemoveProfile.LocalPath)' successfully."} 
                Catch {Write-Host "Delete profile failed." -ForegroundColor Red} 
            } 
            1 {break} 
        } 
    } 
    $ProfileInfo|Select-Object @{Expression = {$_.__SERVER}; Label = "ComputerName"}, ` 
    @{Expression = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)}; Label = "LastUseTime"},` 
    @{Name = "Action"; Expression = {If (Test-Path -Path $_.LocalPath) 
            {"Not Deleted"} 
            Else 
            {"Deleted"} 
        }
    } 
}
# End Script
```

Similar approaches can be see here:

> https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/124316-delete-user-profiles-with-powershell
>
> https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-manage-user-profiles

Comment: This does *not* use `CIM`.

Comment: granted, but that last link explicitly does. My response is all about, if one this is not working, one has options.

Comment: The last link explicitly does *not*.  It uses the command once, then abandons it for `Get-WmiObject`

Comment: The point is the OP said what they "found so far", not any finalized thing to satisfy the use case. Again, as you know, and as you have pontificated on this very site In several of your replies, there other ways to do things with PowerShell if you are not having success with X or Y. Even is the OP choose to go CIM, others hitting this discussion may not be able to, so falling back to earlier ways is still valid. Even the OP could run into scenarios where CIM is not possible.

Comment: [There are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735767/delete-user-profile-using-powershell) multiple [questions in a quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549752/delete-user-profiles-with-powershell) search that do WMI deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Take care when deleting profiles, you don't want to hit machine special accounts.  The `Win32_UserProfile` class *has* a `LastUseTime` property you can rely on.

```
$session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $cn
$gcimParams = @{
    'CimSession' = $session
    'ClassName'  = 'Win32_UserProfile'
    'Filter'     = 'RefCount<1 and Special="false" and Loaded="false"'
}
$profileList = (Get-CimInstance @gcimParams).Where{$PSItem.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)}

foreach ($user in $profileList)
{
    $user | Remove-CimInstance -CimSession $session
}
```